# Problem using exec within class' function in Python

Tags: python, class, exec

The following code works as expected

```
name = "Test"
myname = ""
exec('myname ="' + name + '"')
print(myname)
```

Which shows as result:

```
Test
```

### Problem

However, if I define the same within a function in a `class` and execute it I get as result an empty string.

```
class new(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.print(name)

    def print(self, name):
        myname = ""
        exec('myname ="' + name + '"')
        print(myname)

a = new("My name")
```

The above is a toy example code of a bigger code.

### Question

How to define the function so as to get the same result? The exec function is actually needed in the bigger code.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)? What does it say about the behavior in local scopes? Hint, look at the last note.

Comment: Why are you using `exec` at all? I half suspect you *don't* need it as much as you think you do.

Comment: In this example case it's not needed of course. But in the real case I'm working in it's needed to shorten the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a dictionary as the globals (or locals) for `exec`.

```py
def print(self, name):
    d = {"myname": ""}
    exec('myname ="' + name + '"', d)
    print(d["myname"])
```

Comment: Is there no way to assign a value to a variable `myname` within the print function using the `exec` function? I tried what you proposed and it works. But I still can't create a variable named `myname` which gets what I want to be assigned. In particular in my bigger code I need a `DataFrame`  get created using `exec` and then access one of it's columns. I may ask another question maybe...